# Flatbuffers: Access Violation: Endian Scalar

Tags: c++, serialization, binary, flatbuffers

https://pastebin.com/1cZ8M5Zk

Schema:

```
/* Model.fbs
namespace Resource.Model;

struct Vec3 {
x:float;
y:float;
z:float;
}

struct Vec2 {
x:float;
y:float;
}

table MeshData {
Position:[Vec3];
Normal:[Vec3];
TexCoords:[Vec2];
Tangent:[Vec3];
Bitangent:[Vec3];
}

table VertexObject {
MData:MeshData;
Indices:[uint];
MatNameHash:uint;
}

table Model {
Name:uint;
Meshes:[VertexObject];
}

root_type Model;
*/
```

Building:

```
//....
auto a = builder.CreateVectorOfStructs(Positions);
auto b = builder.CreateVectorOfStructs(Normals);
auto c = builder.CreateVectorOfStructs(TexCoords);
auto d = builder.CreateVectorOfStructs(Tangents);
auto e = builder.CreateVectorOfStructs(Bitangents);

auto f = CreateMeshData(builder, a, b, c, d, e);


auto g = builder.CreateVector<uint32_t>(Indices);

unsigned int h = 1024; //Hash of Name of Material

std::vector<flatbuffers::Offset<VertexObject>> VO;
auto i = CreateVertexObject(builder, f, g, h);
auto i2 = CreateVertexObject(builder, f, g, h);

VO.push_back(i);
VO.push_back(i2);

auto j = builder.CreateVector(VO);
//...
```

Loading:

```
auto test = GetModel(data);


assert(test->Name());
auto name = test->Name();

assert(test->Meshes());
auto FBMeshes = test->Meshes();


for (unsigned int i = 0; i < FBMeshes->size(); i++)
{
    assert(FBMeshes->Get(i));
    auto FBMeshesIndex = FBMeshes->Get(i);


    //assert(FBMeshesIndex->MData());
}
```

I get an Access Violation when trying to call a Table Vector in Flatbuffers. Included is the Schema, and Source Code. I believe it to be something to do with how the components serialized together for the MeshData Table, but I am unable to figure out where exactly. I get the Error when I try to run assert(FBMeshesIndex->MData()); which is Root->Vec:Tables()->Get(i)->Vec:Tables() of which contains several Vec of Structs.

> TestBed.exe!flatbuffers::ReadScalar(const void * p) Line 219    C++ Symbols loaded.
>       TestBed.exe!flatbuffers::Table::GetOptionalFieldOffset(unsigned short field) Line 1866  C++ Symbols loaded.
>       TestBed.exe!flatbuffers::Table::GetPointer(unsigned short field) Line 1878   C++ Symbols loaded.
>       TestBed.exe!flatbuffers::Table::GetPointer(unsigned short field) Line 1885   C++ Symbols loaded.
>       TestBed.exe!Resource::Model::VertexObject::MData() Line 180 C++ Symbols loaded.
>       TestBed.exe!main() Line 147 C++ Symbols loaded.
>       [External Code]     Annotated Frame

Comment: You should have just updated your original question, rather than deleting it and generating a new one. This question again doesn't show the code that is actually causing the crash.. and `Root->Vec:Tables()->Get(i)->Vec:Tables()` is not C++ and doesn't correspond to the schema.

Comment: I gave that example, as to make it easier to follow the schema... the Root being the Object loaded, Pointing to the Vector of Tables called the VertexObject, etc. And the syntax is what I believe the documentation showed to be. the error comes when I call `assert(FBMeshesIndex->MData());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks ok, so the problem is likely outside of the code shown, in how `data` was transported from being built to being used.

Is the value of `name` 1024? is `FBMeshes->size()` 2? Additionally, you should run a verifier on `data` prior to accessing it, to see if there were any problems with how the data was passed along.

Comment: Thanks for the help. After reading this, I narrowed the problem down. I commented out all the file loading operations and just loaded the data back by the buffer pointer directly, so it worked. This let me know that it was my File Loading code that was the offender. On Closer inspection, I was reading the file in binary, but I forgot to give my fopen parameter the 'b' in the "wb". Thanks again.